# Default value in core data

Tags: ios, swift

I have core data file generated by my app. This file contains a data. But I don't want this file generate in every user device. I want put this file in app and every user uses this file. How can I do this?

Comment: Do what exactly? Something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101743/preload-database-with-coredata-swift-4) or something else, please clarify what you mean.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'll explain with an example. I have json file with list of cities and I converted this file to CoreData file. Now, then I start app, I don't convert json any more, but if I start app on another simulator it must be converted, and I don't want this, I want use my CoreData file on all devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find answer here:
https://gist.github.com/xavierchia/ef43abb270003ae63e5bbb7eb5404645
I need just copy my SQL files to project and copy them in app directory.